# How to return no record found in jquery filters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a search function .  This is return li if match with text
other wise return null. I  need a message **no record founds** if not matching any li data.

```
search_menu_list() {
    return function (event) {
        let searchText = $.trim($(this).val().toLowerCase());
        if (searchText == '') {
            $('.prio-app-menu-list li').show();
            return;
        }
        $('.prio .prio-app-navigation-footer-module .prio-app-menu-list li').hide();
        $('.prio .prio-app-navigation-footer-module .prio-app-menu-list li').filter(function () {
            // alert($(this).find('div').data('name'));
            return $(this).data('name').toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText) > -1;
        }).show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operator when check for value.

Example:

```
var dt =  $(this).data('name').toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText);
var msg =   dt > -1 ? dt :"No data found";
return msg;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the length

```js
search_menu_list() {
  return function(event) {
    const $list = $('.prio .prio-app-navigation-footer-module .prio-app-menu-list li');
    let searchText = this.value.trim().toLowerCase();
    if (searchText == '') {
      $list.show();
      return;
    }
    $list.hide();
    const $found = $list.filter(function() {
      return $(this).data('name').toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText) > -1;
    })
    if ($found.length>0) $found.show();
    else console.log('No results for',searchText)
  }

}
```